# Saving a file in AWS filesystem

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda

Hi I am trying out opencv in AWS lambda. I want to save a SVM model in txt file so that I can load it again. Is it possible to save it in tmp directory and load it from there whenever I need it or will I have to use s3?

I am using python and trying to do something like this:

```
# saving the model
svm.save("/tmp/svm.dat")
# Loading the model
svm = cv2.ml.SVM_load("/tmp/svm.dat")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible as Lambda execution environment is distributed and therefore the same function might run on several different instances.

The alternative is to save your `svm.dat` to S3 and then download it every time you start your lambda function.

Comment: This is the correct answer, although you should note that AWS Lambda may share execution environments some, it just isn't something that you can predict or rely on 100% of the time. So you should check if the file has already been downloaded into the environment before initiating another download from S3, in order to prevent unnecessary Lambda function startup time.